# Replace some contents of NSMutableDictionary with another NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

i am having 2 NSMutableDictionaries that each has 5 NSArrays inside,

these 2 NSMutableDictionaries have excactly the same 5 keys and NSArrays but with different content,

i need to replace only 2 Arrays with the Arrays of the other NSMutableDictionary
so

```
dic1 = dic2; //isn't a solution...will replace all the contents of the one to the other...
```

i need something that can replace the object of a specific key with the other same key.

i tried

```
[dic1 setObject:[dic2 objectForKey:@"key1"] forKey:@"key1"];
[dic1 setObject:[dic2 objectForKey:@"key2"] forKey:@"key2"];
```

and i get ERROR: attempt to insert nil value (key: key1)'

Comment: 1. Believe the error messages, try to figure out how they apply to what you are doing. 2. Look at the data, the LLDB debugger is a good option and there is always `NSLog'. 3. When there are problems breakup compound statements into intermediate statements so the error can be located.

Comment: `NSMutableDictionaries` are not a good substitute for a Data Model Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error just means `[dic2 objectForKey:@"key1"]` is returning a nil value. In other words, that key does not exist in the dictionary. Likewise, you can't set a nil value inside of an NSDictionary, so thats why the error is sent out.

Print out each of the dictionaries and ensure your keys/values are what you expect. You can use an NSLog or just pause the program with a breakpoint, and enter `po dic1` in the console.